# TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')

Tags: django, django-urls

I used the Django's version is 1.10.4 and was seeing in my file mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^website/$',"website.views.first_page"),
]
```

and views.py in mysite/mysite/

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse

def first_page(request):
    return HttpResponse("<p>hello Django</p>")
```

Did these settings but I always have the current error.Help me.

Comment: Your views.py file is in mysite/mysite/ ..?? IF yes then why are you using **website.views.first_page** in urls.py file ..?? Which one is correct..??

Comment: no,i desc wrong! sorry,the views.py location in  mysite/views.py

Comment: setting in views.py was changed :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String reference is deprecated in Django 1.10.
So, Django 1.10 no longer allows you to specify views as a string in your URL patterns.
You can no longer pass import paths to url(), you need to pass the actual view function.
The solution is to update your urls.py to include the view callable. 
This means that you have to import the view in your urls.py.

Use these urls.py instead :

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.views import first_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^website/$',first_page)
]
```